# Datagridview bind object to column instead to row

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

When binding a List of Objects `List<MyObject>` to a `DataGridView` each column represents a field of the object and each row represents an object.

Is is possible to do this the other way around? I want to have the fields of the object in the rows and each object should represent a column

Comment: I have not a `DataTable`. I have `List<MyObject>` bound to the DataGridView

Comment: I saw that after posting my first comment. Thatswhy I deleted it. `DataGridView` is not designed that way. Atleast with `DataTable` you could transpose it and attach as `DataSource`. Even with this the `DataGridView` behavior remains same. May be you could check some OffTheSelf  DataGrids.

Comment: Can you show with the data/example?

Comment: I think the question is clear.

Comment: I have the same challenge, ended up coding the gridview manually (number 6 here): https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/ways-to-bind-datagridview-in-window-forms-C-Sharp/